# Bounds for coefficients of bounded infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume that $\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\right|\leq1$ holds for all $\lambda\geq 0$, do the coefficients $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ need to be bounded, e.g. $|a_n|\leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you take the unbounded sequence $(a_n)$ of coefficients $a_n=(-1)^{n+1} \,n$, then the sum is $S(\lambda)=\lambda \exp(-2\lambda)$ which satisfies $0\leq S(\lambda)\leq 1$ for all $\lambda\ge0.$